# Memory leak listeners from a view pager when app is closed

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, memory-leaks

I'm trying to implement a horizontal full page scroll view in a fragment but am having trouble with fixing memory leaks. On each view there is a firebase realtime database value event listener that retrieves whether a user has liked or unliked the current content on screen. The functionality works as expected but there is a memory leak detected in `MainActivity` when the back button is used to leave the app. I am using LeakCanary to find memory leaks.

Inside the adapter class for the pager i have:

```
class MediaAdapter(private val uid: String): RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaAdapter.MediaViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MediaViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_pager_media, parent, false)
        return MediaViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: MediaViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        holder.removeListeners()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MediaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentMedia = media[position]
        holder.bind(currentMedia)
    }

    // inner class MediaViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) ...

}
```

I have the ViewHolder as an inner class:

```
inner class MediaViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private lateinit var ref: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var likedListener: ValueEventListener

    fun removeListeners() {
        ref.removeEventListener(likedListener)           
    }

    fun bind(currentMedia: Media) {
        setupListeners(currentMedia)
    }

    private fun setupListeners(currentMedia: Media) {
        ref = Firebase.database.getReference("Likes/${currentMedia.id}")
        setIsLikedListener(uid)
    }

    private fun setIsLikedListener(uid: String) {
        likedListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(uid).exists()) {
                    itemView.like_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp)
                    itemView.like_button.tag = Constant.CONTENT_LIKED
                } else {
                    itemView.like_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp)
                    itemView.like_button.tag = Constant.CONTENT_NOT_LIKED
                }
            }
        }
        ref.addValueEventListener(likedListener)
    }        

}
```

I am using the view pager in a fragment managed from `MainActivity`. Inside this fragment I am setting the adapter to `null` on destroy:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    media_view_pager.adapter = null
}
```

When the app is opened I navigate to the fragment from `MainActivity`.
I'm not calling anything in `onDestroy` in the main activity and the leak log is suggesting the leak is coming from `MainActivity`. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

The LeakCanary log output:

````
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ com.google.firebase.database.core.ZombieEventManager class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static ZombieEventManager.defaultInstance
│                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.firebase.database.core.ZombieEventManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ZombieEventManager.globalEventRegistrations
│                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ HashMap.table
│              ~~~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ HashMap$Node[].[0]
│                     ~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ HashMap$Node.key
│                   ~~~
├─ com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ValueEventRegistration.eventListener
│                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ hydroid.adapters.MediaAdapter$MediaViewHolder$setIsLikedListener$1 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous class implementing com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
│    ↓ MediaAdapter$MediaViewHolder$setIsLikedListener$1.this$0
│                                                        ~~~~~~
├─ hydroid.adapters.MediaAdapter$MediaViewHolder instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ MediaAdapter$MediaViewHolder.itemView
│                                   ~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of hydroid.activities.MainActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is null
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ ConstraintLayout.mContext
╰→ hydroid.activities.MainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because hydroid.activities.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     key = adc0793b-8dec-41da-a565-25b984b9e54a
​     watchDurationMillis = 5167
​     retainedDurationMillis = 167

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 26
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.2
Analysis duration: 4819 ms```
````

Comment: aren't you unregistering the event listener in the `onStop` ?

Comment: No I have not implemented `onStop` in either `MainActivity` or the fragment with the view pager

Comment: i may be wrong but i think leak might be because , the listeners are active when the activity is stoped , and you should not listener for changes when the activity is stoped, because you only want to update UI only when the activity is in forground, so try detaching the listener is `onStop` and see if solves the problem

Comment: yes that seems to be possible. But when `onViewDetachedFromWindow` is called, should that not already unregister the listener? And as it inside the `ViewHolder` I can't access them from the `onStop` method for the fragment or activity. Should I move the listener and reference out of the `ViewHolder` class?

Comment: I moved the listener and the database reference to the `MediaAdapter` class but now they are not working